# Jquery. .each()

Tags: jquery, width, each

I have got this problem where I am not getting the right value of width of li element.

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    var naviLenght = 0;
    var test = $('.navi.holder').width();
    console.log(test)

    $('.navi.item').each(function(){
        naviLenght += $(this).width();
    }); 

    console.log(naviLenght);
});
```

So basically **I am trying to get the width of all the li in my navibar** by using `$.each()` function but it is not giving me the correct width that it actually has. **The width of the navibar is 310px but the value I am getting inside `.each()` is 197px** ?

What am I doing wrong?

Here is the html of the navibar:

```
<ul class="navi holder">
  <li><a href="#" class="navi item">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="navi item">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="navi item">About us</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="navi item">Order</a></li>
</ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bHaLB/

So I've change some things on jsfiddle and now it gives me 309px but I got the same code on my computer and it says 277px :S when I try IE and Firefox it says 283 ? o.O

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem with your code is that you are using [width()](https://api.jquery.com/width/) *which does not count for padding and border* but it looks like from your argument you want to include them as well. Try *jQuery.outerWidth()*

```
$('.navi.item').each(function(){
  naviLenght += $(this).outerWidth();
});
```

What jQuery doc says about [outerWidth](http://api.jquery.com/outerwidth/)

> Get the current computed width for the first element in the set of matched elements, including padding and border.

Comment: Tried and then I got 277px